# what program is responsible to create "C:\_backup\MXCYCLE""

Tags: windows

what program is responsible to create and use "C:_backup\MXCYCLE" ?
it contains over a Gig of misc files, my files.

Comment: `_backup` could be a user-created folder. Do other people use, administer, or fix your machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SystemSuite 7 creates a folder with the name mxcycle.  It is part of an undelete feature.  Do you have that program installed?